# HuggingFace Pipeline: UserWarning: `grouped_entities` is deprecated and will be removed in version v5.0.0. How to improve about this warning?

Tags: python, warnings, pipeline, huggingface-transformers

I am using the following code

```
!pip install datasets transformers[sentencepiece]
from transformers import pipeline
ner = pipeline("ner", grouped_entities=True, model='dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english') #Named Entity Recognition (NER)
ner("My name is <Name> and I work at <Office> in <location>.")
```

And I got the following warning. How to improve upon this warning?

> UserWarning: `grouped_entities` is deprecated and will be removed in
> version v5.0.0, defaulted to
> `aggregation_strategy="AggregationStrategy.SIMPLE"` instead.

Comment: Please share all your code. What is *pipeline*?

Comment: Code added. It's a huiggingface code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[HuggingFace]: Pipelines - class transformers.TokenClassificationPipeline](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.18.0/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TokenClassificationPipeline) (***emphasis*** is mine):

- **grouped_entities** (`bool`, *optional*, defaults to False) - ***DEPRECATED, use `aggregation_strategy` instead***. Whether or not to group the tokens corresponding to the same entity together in the predictions or not.

So, your line of code could be:

```py
ner = pipeline("ner", aggregation_strategy="simple", model="dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english")  # Named Entity Recognition (NER)
```